# Showing visitors ping to certain server on website?

Tags: php, html, ping

I'm interested to know as to how http://plugpayplay.com/gameservers.php (on that page) shows the visitor their average ping to the servers listed.

How would a similar system work?

Regards.

Comment: What would you code to do it?

Comment: I'd like to know how to do it in something such as PHP if it's possible, taking into account the ping has to be calculated from several servers

Comment: I think it would be intersting to imagine the algorithm involving it. I suppose they may have several servers around the world and then gather information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the source of the page?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript"> ping('l0','193.0.159.140',1); </script>
```

http://plugpayplay.com/js/ping.js (Note: possible copyrights?)

Only PHP, would be to get the remote IP plugged in I think.

Comment: Interesting. I'll see about the copyrights of the script! Thanks

Comment: 'copyright' sounds kinda silly now I read it, basically meant I was linking to code that someone else wrote.  pretty basic though after looking at it.  Just don't straight copy and paste :)